# C# Exception User Handle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

Does anybody knows about this? I'm having trouble in the code that has been given on me.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Source Error:

```
Line 21:                 string checkuser = "select count(*) from 1Database where StudentName='" + txtStudentName.Text + "'";
Line 22:                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
Line 23:                 int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
Line 24: 
Line 25:                 if (temp == 1)
```

Source File: C:\Users\orall\source\repos\DatabaseConnection\DatabaseConnection\loginpage.aspx.cs    Line: 23

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '1'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2582782 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6033430
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +297
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4291
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +91
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +446
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2698
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +1611
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +65
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +283
DatabaseConnection.loginpage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\orall\source\repos\DatabaseConnection\DatabaseConnection\loginpage.aspx.cs:23
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +52
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +97
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +61
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +693

Comment: `1Database` in your SQL command, is that right?

Comment: 1Database is not a legal name for a SQL Server database. A database name must follow the [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers).

Comment: And then try and see whether student `"O'Brien"` exists

Comment: oh.. sorry, I'm just experimenting on it so if I ever Apply it sure it'll work.

thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Try this query assuming that Students is a datatable name:

```
tring checkuser = "select count(*) from Students where StudentName='" + txtStudentName.Text + "'";
```

and I recommend to use a parameter instead of txtStudentName.Text

And IMHO this looks better

```
var temp = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```